# What was the big circle on the ground during a boss fight?

Tags: back-4-blood

I was fighting an Ogre in Back 4 Blood, and my team decided to kite it back to a minigun we'd passed a minute ago.

The Ogre followed us partway, then stopped. It may have been because the minigun was staggering it, or it may have been that it was programmed to not progress any further in that direction. It wasn't clear to me at the time, being fairly new to the game.

Anyway, after a bit of this, a huge "circle" spawned on the ground, kind of like the edge of the world in a battle royale game. Standing outside it seemed to deal damage, so I stepped inside quickly. The minigun was also outside the circle, so the teammate on there left and we dispatched the Ogre the normal way.

Then the circle disappeared, and we continued to progress as normal.

So, uh, what? What was that? What are the conditions for its spawn? For its removal? What exactly does it do?

I found this video on the same level where something similar happens:

Shortly after the player in the video starts shooting the breaker, you can hear an intense sound effect and the clouds in the distance become yellowish. This was the same thing that happened to me, although the circle is centered elsewhere so you can't see its edge on the ground like in my game. The instant the breaker died, the effect ended.